# Altering CSS markup

Tags: theming, 8

I would like to add custom property on drupal's stylesheets `<link />` tag. I tried following in `hook_css_alter`:

```
foreach ($css as &$style) {
  $style['#attributes']['property'] = 'stylesheet';
  $style['#attributes'] = ['property' => 'stylesheet'];
  $style['property'] = 'stylesheet';
  $style['element']['#theme'] = 'stylesheet';
  $style['#markup'] = '<stylesheet />';
  $style['element']['#markup'] = '<stylesheet />';
}
```

Nothing seeps to do any changes, and I feel like I am guessing around. So how to properly alter `<link />` elements markup?

Second question would be how to get all stylesheets as array in theme. It seeps that in Drupal 8 beta 10 you cloud just do `{% for style in styles %}` in Your twig template, but with beta 12 update this does not work, `styles` returns placeholder element.

Comment: I don't have the answer (don't have time to check just now either), but just so you're not heading down the wrong path: there's no `template_css_alter()`, you're probably thinking of [`hook_css_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/8) which isn't meant to control the associated markup as far as I know

Comment: Yeah, hook_css_alter, thanks for noticing :). BTW is there any documentation which functions are available in `.theme` file, and witch only in `.modules` (only in modules)? I thought that functions starting with `template_` are meant to use in template and `hook_` are meant to be used in modules, but now I know I was wrong

Comment: Added an answer, but I saw later that this was for D8, if you have any trouble swapping the service, I can provide an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Drupal 8

`$css` variable is converted to an array of <link> tags through `CssCollectionRenderer::render()`, so you just have to swap this service (https://www.drupal.org/node/2026959) and override render function:

```
class MyModuleCssCollectionRenderer extends CssCollectionRenderer {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render(array $css_assets) {
    $elements = parent::render($css_assets)))
    foreach($elements as &$elements) {
      $element['#attributes']['property'] = 'stylesheet';
    }
    return $elements;
  }
}
```

## Drupal 7

The CSS files are managed by `drupal_get_css`. After being altered by hook_css_alter(), `$css` is passed in a render array:

```
// Render the HTML needed to load the CSS.
$styles = array(
  '#type' => 'styles',
  '#items' => $css,
);
```

This render array is declared in system_element_info() as:

```
$types['styles'] = array(
  '#items' => array(),
  '#pre_render' => array('drupal_pre_render_styles'),
  '#group_callback' => 'drupal_group_css',
  '#aggregate_callback' => 'drupal_aggregate_css'
);
```

As you can see there is a pre-render callback `drupal_pre_render_styles()`, this is the function responsible for converting the `$css` variable to <link> tags. This is where you can work, just add you own callback in a `hook_element_info_alter()`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 */
function mymodule_element_info_alter(&$types) {
  // Add a pre_render callback to styles.
  $types['styles']['#pre_render'][] = 'mymodule_pre_render_styles';
}

/**
 * Append property to stylesheet <link> tags.
 */
function mymodule_pre_render_styles($elements) {
    foreach($elements as &$element) {
        $element['#attributes']['property'] = 'stylesheet';
    }
}
```